# Define major/minor ticks using bokeh in python

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

Consider the following simple example:

```
# Long range of dates, each given as a string
xLabels = ['2014-08-01', '2014-08-02', '2014-08-03', '2014-08-04', '2014-08-05', '2014-08-06', '2014-08-07', '2014-08-08', '2014-08-09', '2014-08-10', '2014-08-11', '2014-08-12', '2014-08-13', '2014-08-14', '2014-08-15', '2014-08-16', '2014-08-17', '2014-08-18', '2014-08-19', '2014-08-20', '2014-08-21', '2014-08-22', '2014-08-23', '2014-08-24', '2014-08-25', '2014-08-26', '2014-08-27', '2014-08-28', '2014-08-29', '2014-08-30', '2014-08-31', '2014-09-01', '2014-09-02', '2014-09-03', '2014-09-04', '2014-09-05', '2014-09-06', '2014-09-07', '2014-09-08', '2014-09-09', '2014-09-10', '2014-09-11', '2014-09-12', '2014-09-13', '2014-09-14', '2014-09-15', '2014-09-16', '2014-09-17', '2014-09-18', '2014-09-19', '2014-09-20', '2014-09-21', '2014-09-22', '2014-09-23', '2014-09-24', '2014-09-25', '2014-09-26', '2014-09-27', '2014-09-28', '2014-09-29', '2014-09-30', '2014-10-01', '2014-10-02', '2014-10-03', '2014-10-04', '2014-10-05', '2014-10-06', '2014-10-07', '2014-10-08', '2014-10-09', '2014-10-10', '2014-10-11', '2014-10-12', '2014-10-13', '2014-10-14', '2014-10-15', '2014-10-16', '2014-10-17', '2014-10-18', '2014-10-19', '2014-10-20', '2014-10-21', '2014-10-22', '2014-10-23', '2014-10-24', '2014-10-25', '2014-10-26', '2014-10-27', '2014-10-28', '2014-10-29', '2014-10-30', '2014-10-31']
y = np.random.randn(len(xLabels))
myPlot = figure(x_range = xLabels)
myPlot.line(xLabels,y)
myPlot.xaxis.major_label_orientation = np.pi/2
show(myPlot)
```

The x-axis labels of the resulting plot are too dense (and not all are needed). I don't understand how can I only display every `n` tick? How can I define which ticks are major and which are minor?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By passing a list of *strings* as the labels they are considered as *categorical range*. In this case it is not possible to have a distinction between major and minor ticks. See [this cross-post](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/Fnjsy0-D34o) for further details.

Comment: Will add: the standard ticker for categorical ranges just adds a tick for ecery category (not really any other good default policy) I you do keep the ticks as categorical (i.e. strings) you could define a custom `Ticker` class to generate fewer ticks according to whatever is appropriate to your special case. Otherwise, using real datetime values might be a better option.